# Store a file content (binary data) inside plone.app.registry

Tags: plone, z3c.form

I need to store inside **plone.app.registry** binary data in a way compatible from Plone 3.3 to 4.2.

Using simply a `schema.Byte` type I'm able to quickly reach this on Plone 4.2 (not very user friendly, but it works), but not on Plone 3.3.

On Plone 3.3 the registry is displyaing a file upload control, but when I try to get the saved data I found that it simply stored a string like:

`'<... HTTPFileUpload...>'`

...so a python repr of an object.

How can I fix this? I need to use *plone.namedfile* product with *collective.z3cform.filewidget*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since plone.formwidget.namedfile 1.0.12 you can use that wigets on ASCII fields also. Data is then converted to base64. Plone 5 uses that feature for it's site logo, which is stored in the registry.

For an example, see the Plone 4 backport of that feature: https://github.com/collective/collective.sitelogo

Especially:

Usage of an `ASCII` field for your image: https://github.com/collective/collective.sitelogo/blob/master/src/collective/sitelogo/interfaces.py#L14

Changing the controlpanel widget for the `ASCII` field to `NamedImageFieldWidget`: https://github.com/collective/collective.sitelogo/blob/master/src/collective/sitelogo/controlpanel.py#L19

Answer (score 4):

plone.app.registry is not really designed to store binary data. It is designed to be simple, lightweight and migration-proof.

What are you trying to achieve with this? There is probably a better way.

Comment: I need to store a file that is not a CMS content, but need to be used for backend configuration.

The only other way I can find is to store it as a fake content type (thing that I neved liked) or a Zope "File"...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seems that you can have the same behavior also on Plone 3; in only needed an upgrade of plone.z3cform